# vba if cells do not equal values then delete

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm fairly new to VBA and I can't seem to figure this one out through google.

I'm trying to run through a worksheet and use an If statement to delete unnecessary columns, based on their row 1 values. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
    Sub Macro1
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Rows("1")
    If cell.Value <>  "order_number", "tax_details", "etc"
    Then .EntireColumn.delete
    End Sub
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to use the "If cell.Value" statement with multiple values, nor how to delete the columns that I don't want. Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,

Justin

Edit: Thanks for all the responses guys, everything was super helpful. Fixed the problem and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other response seems to be addressing the fact that you looping left-to-right while deleting columns. Delete rows from bottom to top and delete columns from right to left or you risk skipping over cells/columns.

```
Sub Macro1
    Dim i as long

    with worksheets("sheet1")
        For i=.cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column to 1 step-1
            select case lcase(.cells(1, i).value)
                case "order_number", "tax_details", "etc"
                    'do nothing
                case else
                    .columns(i).entirecolumn.delete
            end select
        next i
    end with
End Sub
```

Comment: trying to under the syntax of the "For" line. Why did you use "end(xltoleft).column instead of "end(xltoright)"? If you're stepping backward wouldn't your beginning column need to be the last one? Or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: I don't start from A1 and look right. I start at XFD1 (.cells(1, **.columns.count**)) and look left. Much more reliable in all situations.

Answer (score 2):

You are close.

1. Your `For` loop must be ended with a `Next` statement
2. your `Then` must occur on the same line as your `If` to be valid and should be closed with an `End If` (unless you do a one-liner)
3. You must test your conditions separately with an `AND` separating them
4. `Cell` is already a keyword here (subclass of a `Range`) so change that variable to `rngCell` or something different.
5. `Rows("1")` would be better as an explicit range otherwise it will literally loop through every column in that row. That's a lot of columns.

---

```
Sub Macro1
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Range("A1:GZ1").Cells
        If rngCell.Value <>  "order_number" And rngCell.Value <>  "tax_details" AND rngCell.Value <> "etc" Then 
             rngCell.EntireColumn.delete
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than using an arbitrary range, I suggest using `For Each rngCell in Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeValues)` to ensure that you will always get all cells with values in them. If there is any data after GZ1, this will ignore it.

Comment: That's a much nicer way. `Range("A1").End("xlToRight")` may be of use here too. As long as it's not straight `Row(1)`

Comment: You will need to loop right to left, or risk missing some deletions

Comment: It would be better to Union the deletion set and delete them all later. You're examining the column headers from left to right.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers. Is there a way to loop right to left with the For Each function?

Answer (score 1):

In order to test multiple conditions, you use logical operators(AND, OR, NOT, etc) to create a single logical statement(i.e. a single value for all 3). If you want any of the conditions to work, use "or" and if you need all 3 conditions to be met, use AND.

```
If cell.Value <>  "order_number", "tax_details", "etc"
```

should be

```
If cell.Value <> "order_number" OR cell.value <> "tax_details"  OR cell.value <> "etc" then
```

To delete the entire column that way, you'd need to reference which column you're trying to delete. If you're iterating over the rows, you'd access it by

```
Cell.EntireColumn.delete
```

Answer (score 0):

You must compare/evaluate each time.

```
If cell.Value <> "order_number" And cell.Value <> "tax_details" And cell.Value <> "etc"
```